# Saving state of object if changes are made - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 7
```

I have the following:

```
controllers/orders_controller.rb

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to order_url(@order), notice: "Order was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to order_url(@order), notice: "Order was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @order.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url, notice: "Order was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:country, :sku, :abbreviation, :description)
    end
end

models/order.rb

class Order < ApplicationRecord
end
```

What I would like to do, is create an OrderHistory Model, with the following fields:

```
order_id (int)
order_history (JSON)
```

When an update is made to the order, I would like the DB entry for the original order, saved as a JSON to OrderHistory.

What I am having trouble with, is creating a variable that contains the state of the existing order, when I enter the controller, without making it available to all app users. Any ideas?

Comment: Rather than trying to do this yourself (unless this is merely a personal exercise) I would highly recommend looking into available libraries like [paper_trail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail), or [audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited). That being said the "original order" will be `@order` before you call `update`.

Comment: Doing this as a personal exercise